# Returning Deleted Rows in SQLite

Tags: sql, c, sqlite, sql-delete

For performance reasons, I want to run an SQLite query that deletes rows AND returns the deleted rows so I don't have to run two separate queries when I want to know what is being deleted. PostOgreSQL allows this using something like "RETURNING *" at the end, but I can't find anything in the documentation for SQLite. How do I do this?

This is what I have currently. The "%s" parts are replaced with inputs, of course (and I sanitize the inputs):

```
"DELETE FROM '%s' WHERE ( username1 = '%s' OR username2 = '%s' ) AND uid = '%s'"
```

In case it matters, I'm programming in C, using the SQLite code from sqlite.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the OLD alias. This should get you the results you are needing.

Comment: How would it be possible to get the data out of a trigger?

Comment: You would write your sql the same way normally done in a trigger but you could pull the older value by using the keyword OLD.somename where somename is the name of the attribute you have now changed. There are some forums on the internet that same you can do this by placing the old and new values in a temporary table but that is not needed. Try the OLD keyword in your select statement.

Comment: And once you have pulled that data, how would the trigger *return* it? SELECT statements in a trigger do not return anything to the application.

Comment: If you are using it with a trigger you may be able to get what you need by first creating a temporary table for which you can place the old value into it and use a select statement to get the old value from after the trigger executes successfully.So what I am saying is create a temp table and use a select statement after the trigger is finished and you are back to the calling program.

Comment: CL you are wrong on that one. I am inserting text from a SQLite source book below.                                                             Both the WHEN clause and the trigger body have access to some additional column qualifiers.
Columns associated with the trigger table (or view) may be qualified with the pseudo-identifier
NEW (in the case of INSERT and UPDATE triggers) or OLD (in the case of UPDATE and DELETE triggers).
These represent the before and after values of the row in question and are only valid for the
current row that caused the trigger to fire. (SQLite, O'reilly 2010)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand it now, but adding to a temporary table then retrieving from that table would take more time than selecting then deleting, right? It would involve a DELETE, an INSERT, and a SELECT rather than a SELECT and a DELETE, though the INSERT and SELECT in this example might be faster... I don't know how SQLite works exactly.

Comment: Here is an example from the text I placed above. It should get you going in the right direction. As CL stated above a trigger does not return anything. So I would suggest you create a temporary table of even add a column to the table that holds your data so you can query the table for the old value. CREATE TRIGGER database_name.trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON table_name FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN stmt1; stmt2; END;
CREATE TRIGGER access_audit BEFORE UPDATE ON access FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO audit_trail VALUES ( OLD.level, NEW.level, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );
 END;

Comment: Also, please mark my answer as the correct one. Thanks!

Comment: This answers the question (I'll mark it as the answer unless a better solution is proposed soon), but it takes longer, right? Since the workaround is slower, I'll have to do what CL. said, so I kinda wish I could accept two answers! Anyway thanks for the example. I didn't know about triggers before.

Comment: Its not a longer work around. If you want to get the obtain the old value anytime you add a column to hold the old value to the table you are working with. If you only want to access the old value right after the trigger updates the table you would create a temporary table to hold the value from which you would get the value from with a simple select statement. CL was wrong in that the OLD function is valid with SQLite. I have shown you several ways to do this. The situation you are in will determine how you set this up. I have shown you both ways from which you can do this easily.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has no such function.

The easiest way is to run two separate queries.

Comment: I'm really surprised it doesn't have it.